# QT5 custom widget with .ui file - calling Ui::myWidget.setupUi required when displaying it

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtwidgets

I created QT custom widget `MyWidget` with a `.ui` file. But when I place `QWidget` to `MainWindow`  in QT designer and promote it to `MyWidget`, **it just renders an empty widget**.

I figured out why it doesn't work. In generated file `ui_mainwindow.h` in function `setupUi` is code for displaying my widget following:

```cpp
widget = new MyWidget(centralWidget);
widget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("widget"));
verticalLayout->addWidget(widget);
```

It works, when I call `Ui::MyWidget.setupUi` (replace the code above with following):

```cpp
widget = new MyWidget(centralWidget);
Ui::MyWidget uiOfWidget;
uiOfWidget.setupUi(widget);
widget->setObjectName(QString::fromUtf8("widget"));
verticalLayout->addWidget(widget);
```

So my question is, how it's possible to reach one of following:

- Generate code like this automatically when compiling `MainWindow.ui` file
- Remove the need for calling `Ui::MyWidget.setupUi`
- Or other fix...?

I use QT5.  Thank you!

Comment: Normally I call setupUi  in the constructor for MyWidget just like I would do for any other widget that uses a `.ui`

Answer (score 0):

As [@drescherjm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/487892/drescherjm) pointed out, the solution is to call `Ui::MyWidget.setupUi` in constructor of `MyWidget`:

```cpp
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget* parent, Qt::WindowFlags f): QWidget(parent, f) {
    Ui::MyWidget ui;
    ui.setupUi(this);
}
```